# How to perform a rolling summation and multiplication in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, rolling-computation

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[100,100,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1.03, 1.02, 0.97, 1.02, 0.92, 1.08, 1.03 ,1.02, 1.03, 0.98],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]).T
df.index = ['2017-12-30', '2017-12-30', '2017-12-31','2018-01-01','2018-01-01',
            '2018-01-02','2018-01-02','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-03']
```

With output:

```
                0     1    2
2017-12-30  100.0  1.03  0.0
2017-12-30  100.0  1.02  0.0
2017-12-31    0.0  0.97  0.0
2018-01-01    0.0  1.02  0.0
2018-01-01    0.0  0.92  0.0
2018-01-02    0.0  1.08  0.0
2018-01-02    0.0  1.03  0.0
2018-01-02    0.0  1.02  0.0
2018-01-03    0.0  1.03  0.0
2018-01-03    0.0  0.98  0.0
```

I want however to transform this DataFrame to a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
                0     1    2
2017-12-30  100.00  1.03   3.0
2017-12-30  100.00  1.02   2.0
2017-12-31  105.00  0.97  -3.15
2018-01-01  101.85  1.02   2.037
2018-01-01  101.85  0.92  -8.15
2018-01-02  95.737  1.08   7.65
2018-01-02  95.737  1.03   2.87
2018-01-02  95.737  1.02   1.91
2018-01-03  108.17  1.03   3.25
2018-01-03  108.17  0.98  -2.16
2018-01-04  109.26  np.nan  np.nan
```

Calculation performed is as follows:
To calculate the first 2 values of the last columns.

```
100 * (1.03-1) = 3
100 * (1.02 -1) = 2
```

Then the third value in the first column will be:

```
100 + 3 + 2 = 105
```

To calculate the value of the third row of the last column.

```
105 * (0.97-1) = -3.15
```

Then the fourth and fifth values (date related) in the first columns will be:

```
105 -3.15 = 101.85
```

To calculate the fourth and fifth values of the last columns.

```
 101.85 * (1.02-1) = 2.037
 101.85 * (0.92-1) = -8.15
```

This continues till all the values are filled in.

`Columns 2` is `column 0` times `column 1 - 1`. `Columns 0` results from a `summation` of the past(time related) values of `column 2`.

Every row of each day has the same values for column 0. And this is achieved by a summation of past(before this specific date) values of column 2.

Anything would help!

Comment: I don't fully understand your formula.  It looks like the values of `df[2]` depend on `df[0]`, but that the values of `df[0]` depend on the values of `df[1]`.  Why isn't the second value of `df[1]` `103`, for example?

Comment: looks like a recursion. If you do not want to go with closed form solution (if exist), then a for loop is the way to go.

Comment: I have added some comments to clarify. The values of df[1] don't depend on any other values.  Yes it sure does look like a for loop.

Comment: what is the size of your real dataframe?

Comment: The real dataframe has an length of more than 3000

Comment: why for the 4th and 5th you do 105 -3.15 +2.077 = 103.85 knowing that 2.077 it is actually the result of the 4th row? should it be only 105 -3.15?

Comment: You are right! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only have 3000ish rows and vectorizing these kind of operation is hard, you can go using a loop for.

```
#initiate varaibles
res_col2 = []
res_col0 = []
s = 0 # same date result sum
# initiate values
mult = df.iloc[0,0]
idx0 = df.index[0]

# loop with iteritems, not too bad with 3000 rows
for idx, val in (df[1]-1).iteritems(): #note the -1 is here already
    # update the mult and idx0 in case of not same date
    if idx != idx0:
        mult += s
        idx0 = idx
        s = 0
    # calculate the result
    r = mult*val
    s += r
    res_col2.append(r)
    res_col0.append(mult)

df[0] = res_col0
df[2] = res_col2
```

and you get:

```
print(df)
                    0     1         2
2017-12-30  100.00000  1.03  3.000000
2017-12-30  100.00000  1.02  2.000000
2017-12-31  105.00000  0.97 -3.150000
2018-01-01  101.85000  1.02  2.037000
2018-01-01  101.85000  0.92 -8.148000
2018-01-02   95.73900  1.08  7.659120
2018-01-02   95.73900  1.03  2.872170
2018-01-02   95.73900  1.02  1.914780
2018-01-03  108.18507  1.03  3.245552
2018-01-03  108.18507  0.98 -2.163701
```